# Javascript speedup in Firefox 8 private browsing?

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, private

I noticed a very significant increase in javascript performance in Firefox 8 when I enable private browsing mode -strange! This in a pretty heavily scripted page. Any ideas what might cause this?

Hope to get some clues as to what might cause this -or rather the slowdown in "normal mode"- I'd love to be able to get the same snappiness without private browsing on. Thanks for reading!

Comment: You may be able to find some clues by working out where the speedup occurs.  Is it on load?  Is it during some interaction?  Does the page use cookies?

Comment: No real difference on load, the strange thing is that the slowdown is in animation of css and interaction with a lot of mouse events. No cookies involved either... (Sorry not to be able to be more specific, but I'm clueless here...)

Comment: It's really hard to say without the actual page it happens on.  Would you be able to post a link to such a page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have addons? Have you tought benchmarking without addons?

Comment: No difference when I disable all addons... Still snappy in private, not so much in normal mode.

Comment: It is because Private Browsing disables a lot of stuff, like addons and cookie/history storing.

Comment: Thanks -the weird thing is though: none of these things seem to be happening during the bits of execution that get bogged down.